# Safari not repainting element above css animation

Tags: javascript, html, css, safari

my code looks like this:

```js
var text = document.getElementById('text');
var toggle = true;

setInterval(function(){
    if (toggle){
       text.innerHTML = 'text1';
    } else {
       text.innerHTML = 'text2';
    }
    toggle = !toggle;
}, 500)
```

```css
#text{
    position: relative;
    background-color: white;
    z-index: 2;
    padding: 0 10px;

}
#marqueeContainer{
    z-index: 1;
}
@keyframes marquee{
    from {
        transform: translateX(100%);
    }
    to {
        transform: translateX(-100%);
    }
}
#marquee {
    animation: marquee 10s linear infinite;
    display: inline-block;

}
```

```html
<span id="text">
    text
</span>
    
<span id="marqueeContainer">
    <span id="marquee">
        marquee 
        marquee 
        marquee 
        marquee 
        marquee 
    </span>
</span>
```

or take a look here:
https://codepen.io/jacquesknie/pen/ZEExZNy

There is this text which is toggled with a setInterval and as soon as there is an animation running underneath Safari is not updating/repainting the text. Chrome and Firefox are behaving just fine. What is going on, am I overlooking something obvious?

Thank a lot,
Jacques

Comment: Interesting. When you remove the `display: inline-block;` style from the `#marquee` selector, it works as expected. No idea why.

Comment: I need the `display: inline-block` because my actual code looks more like this: https://codepen.io/jacquesknie/pen/dyyeZNG

Answer (score -1):

On Safari you must use

`@-webkit-keyframes`

See https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariCSSRef/Articles/OtherStandardCSS3Features.html

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't change anything. Safari still does not repaint. Also Safari seems to accept keyframes without prefix since version 9: https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation